# C++ - Alphabetizing Strings - '<' Operator Overload

Tags: c++, string, operator-overloading, alphabetical

For starters this is homework, I have a good understanding of what i'm supposed to do but I am obviously missing something.

I currently have an abstract base class called "Person". And I have 3 classes that inherit person they are Staff, Faculty, and Student.

I am trying to organize all the "Person's" names by last name. So I must overload the '<' operator.

I have the function written but I just don't know where to put it.

**Function:**

```
bool operator < ( const Faculty &right )
        {
            if( getLastName() >= right.getLastName() == 0 )
                return true;
            return false;
        }
```

Should I put this in the header file for all my derived classes, or should I put it as a virtual function in the base class Person? Or should I do Both. Currently I am doing both and I'm getting an error for every file.

**error:**

```
error C2662: 'Person::getLastName' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from
```

**Update:**
I have changed my function to:

```
    bool operator < ( const Person &right )
    {
        return LastName >= right.getLastName(); 
    }
```

After getting advice from other people, I have only placed this function in "Person" and made it not virtual. Yet I am still getting 5 of the same exact errors that all point to this function.

**Error:**

```
'Person::getLastName' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const Person' to 'Person &'
```

If it helps anyone at all here is the code to my "Person.h":

```
class Person
{
    private:
        string FirstName,
               LastName,
               MiddleName,
               SSN;

        string FullName;

    public:
        Person();
        Person(string, string, string, string);
        Person(string);

        string getFirstName();
        string getLastName();
        string getMiddleName();
        string getSSN();
        string getFullName();

        void setFirstName(string);
        void setLastName(string);
        void setMiddleName(string);
        void setSSN(string);
        void setFullName(string);

        virtual string getIdentity()
        {
            return FirstName + " " + MiddleName + " " + LastName + " " + SSN;
        }

        bool operator < ( const Person &right )
        {
            return LastName >= right.getLastName(); 
        }

        virtual string getPurpose() = 0;

};
```

Comment: Your error output is cut off.  Please post the entire error message.

Comment: The error isn't really related to your question: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s2d2tez%28VS.80%29.aspx `getLastName` should be a `const` member function. (I guess that `getLastName` is non-const on the basis that your `operator<` is non-const).

Comment: @Steve Jessop: you don't know that the error relates to `const`-ness, because you can't see the error.  Your link merely suggests that the problem might relate to `const`-ness.

Comment: @robert: educated guess, as explained in my comment.

Comment: I have added updates to my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you get probably occurs when you try to call the operator on a `const` object. The compiler doesn't know that `operator<` doesn't change the object it is called on and therefore gives an error. To ensure that the function doesn't change the object, declare the function as `const`:

```
bool operator < ( const Faculty &right ) const {
   ...
}
```

This way the function can also be called on constant objects. `getLastName()` probably also should be `const`.

Comment: Too bad the compiler does not deduce constness. It seems to me there are many cases where it could, including this one.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, you want this to work on all people, so you should put it in Person. And you want to compare any two people, so the RHS should be person.

Also, your logic is a double negative. I'm not sure why you would do that, when...

```
bool operator < ( const Person &right )
        {
            return getLastName() < right.getLastName();
        }
```

... makes a lot more sense.

Comment: I changed all that stuff and I just put the function in "Person" but I am still getting 5 of the same errors pointing to the same exact line.
 
Error 1 error C2662: 'Person::getLastName' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const Person' to 'Person &' – Johnny Whisman 0 secs ago edit

Answer (score 2):

it looks like you might need to add or change your getters from:

```
    string getFirstName();
    string getLastName();
    string getMiddleName();
    string getSSN();
    string getFullName();
```

into

```
    string getFirstName() const;
    string getLastName() const;
    string getMiddleName() const;
    string getSSN() const;
    string getFullName() const;
```

This is because the function giving you errors doesn't have a mutable version of the Person instance, But there are no `const` getters, so it can't use any getters at all!

Answer (score 1):

You should put it in your Person class, and it doesn't need to be virtual if you can't imagine a derived class needing to change the ordering.  Given sorting of names doesn't seem to be something that would differ for the different categorisations of Person, `virtual` isn't indicated.

The argument should be a `const Person&`, and the function itself should be made `const` (put that just before the `{` introducing the implementation, or - if the implementation is out of line, before the trailing `;`.

EDIT: I've added an implementation below.

Things to note:

- `operator<` is a member function, so can access private member variables without needing to go through public member functions (e.g. `getLastName()`).  Using public member functions is nicer in one sense (less chance of needing to be rewritten due to implementation changes), but I've been lazy below and used the shorter direct access.
- The cascading comparisons to ensure we compare on other fields when `LastName`s are equal, and so on.  This concludes with comparing the SSN, which I assume is unique, to ensure that even two people with the same name will have a predictable, repeatable ordering.  That's essential if you want to have a "stable" sort order for `Person` objects, e.g. necessary to use these objects in a `std::map<Person, XXX>`.  It's a good rule of thumb to write `operator<` to be stable like this, although it tends to be a bit more verbose and can sometimes be slower to execute.

Implementation:

```
bool operator<(const Person& right) const
{ 
    return LastName < right.LastName ? true :
           LastName > right.LastName ? false :
           FirstName < right.FirstName ? true :
           Firstname > right.FirstName ? false :
           MiddleName < right.MiddleName ? true :
           MiddleName > right.MiddleName ? false :
           SSN < right.SSN; // assume SSN is guaranteed unique
}
```

...another popular way of writing this is...

```
bool operator<(const Person& right) const
{ 
    return LastName < right.LastName ||
           LastName == right.LastName &&
               (FirstName < right.FirstName ||
                Firstname == right.FirstName &&
                    (MiddleName < right.MiddleName ||
                     MiddleName == right.MiddleName &&
                         SSN < right.SSN)); // assume SSN is guaranteed unique
}
```

Comment: I changed all that stuff and I just put the function in "Person" but I am still getting 5 of the same errors pointing to the same exact line.

Comment: Error 1 error C2662: 'Person::getLastName' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const Person' to 'Person &'

Comment: @Johnny Whisman: Your updated code doesn't show the `const` as recommended in the second paragraph of this answer.

Comment: @Johnny: you also need to make all the functions that don't set/modify the member variables `const`, then it will be consistent and work properly.  Why?  Because if you have a `const Person&` then you can only call `const` member functions on that person... you need to call `GetLastName()`, so it must be `const` too.